# Ceiling fan with light.

Tags: electrical

My ceiling fan does not work. I have a ceiling fan light and the fan does not turn. It just hums but the light works.  What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If it hums then it's getting power to it. A very common thing for them is when the bearings (or bushing) in the motor get dry and begin to stick. A friend of mine had his house catch on fire because of a stuck fan motor. Sometimes it can be lubed (fan turned off) by spraying something like WD40 around the motor shaft right behind the fan itself and then turning the fan by hand until it frees up. The other way is to replace the unit and be sure.